# Unable to connect to SQL Server 2014 remotely

Tags: sql-server

Unable to connect to SQL Server remotely

I have installed SQL Server 2014 Express on Windows 10. I can connect to server locally by entering: `computername\SQLEXPRESS` or `192.168.0.xxx\SQLEXPRESS`

When I try to connect to the server using public ipadress

```
122.xxx.xxx.xxx\SQLSERVER
```

I get an error:

> Error: 26 - Error Locating Server/Instance Specified) (.Net SqlClient
>   Data Provider)

I also have host name from dlinkddns, tried connecting with host name with same error.

Steps which I have tried:

1. Enabled remote connections.
2. Configured 1433 TCP port to be allowed in firewall. Disabled antivirus program. I tried disabling firewall with no success.
3. Enabled all protocols "TCP/IP', 'Named Pipes', 'Shared memory'
4. Under TCP/IP properties, changed 'IP All' 'TCP Port' to 1433. I tried enabling IP1 to public ipadress with port 1433 with no success.
5. I have dlink DIR 816 router, i dont see anything called port forwarding instead it has 'port triggering', i configured to allow port 1433 TCP and 1434 UDP.
6. I can ping both ipadress and hostname with success but the server would not connect.

I have tried everything to the best of my knowledge but nothing works, any inputs to setup my connection remotely will be of great help!

Comment: Have you started SQL Server Browser service?

Comment: If the **instance** name on the server is `SQLEXPRESS` - why are you trying to connect to `122.xxx.xxx.xxx\SQLSERVER` ?? Have you tried: `122.xxx.xxx.xxx\SQLEXPRESS` ??

Comment: Apologies for the typo, i tried with 122.xxx.xxx.xxx\SQLEXPRESS with same error.

Comment: Yes, SQL browser service is started and checked running.

Comment: Could be a firewall issue (hardware or software).

Answer (score 1):

The error is pretty specific here.

```
error: 26 - Error Locating Server/Instance Specified (.Net SqlClient Data Provider)
```

You must understand one thing. Your local IP (192.168.0.xxx) is not visible from WWW. Only your Public IP or Global IP is. Once someone comes inside your network they will be able to ping your IP (192.168.0.xxx).

To make it work, you must have the SQL Server installed in a computer whose local IP is accessible from the internet. **That means, it should be hosted in a Domain.**

[Connecting to SQL Server over the Internet](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175483%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)

Comment: Which means only choice for SQL server to allow remote connection is to be hosted on a domain and all users has to be a part of domain to connect remotely?

Comment: That is true. Basically, if you tell me to ping your local IP address I wont be able to do it(or may be I will be pinging a local IP on my network) but I will be able to ping 122.XXX.XXX.XXX because its global.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I dont think setting up domain will be feasible and so i have to look for other alternatives. To you second point, thats why we have port forwarding right, to forward request to local IPadress which are sent from public ipadress. Correct me if im wrong here.

Comment: @Mike, you might want to check this link : https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175483%28v=sql.105%29.aspx, I have updated the answer.

Answer (score 1):

We can connect to SQL Server remotely over the internet if the Server has a static public IP address and port forwarding is configured on the router to allow remote connection requests through the router firewall.

In the router firewall settings, there is normally a games and application section, in there add SQL application and give the port range (1433 normally) and then direct the incoming connection by selecting the SQL Server device name on the network.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the issue by adding local ip into DMZ on my router. Everything works like a charm now.

Comment: can you please explain more detail of your answer, how you have solved the problem ?

Comment: most of the modern routers have something called DMZ (Demilitarized Zone) built in, access GUI of the router and look for DMZ and just add your local ipadress into it. If you need anything in specific, let me know.